# How I can view recently svn repository?

Tags: linux, svn, command-line-interface, solaris, repository

How I can view recently svn repository ?

Comment: I think your question lacks a verb. What Repos do you want to view? Recently _changed_ Repos?

Comment: yes i want to find Recently changed Repos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the most recent revision of a repository with the `svnlook youngest` command

`svnlook youngest /path/to/repository`

this will give you revision number. To find out the changes associated with that revision use
the `svnlook changed` command. Assuming you revision number is 9

`svnlook changed -r 9 /path/to/repository`